# Using dynamic import with videos on React with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, async-await, html5-video, react-hooks

I am making a kind of personal website with a full screen video in background. And **I need to load a different video for different screen sizes**. I am using React, and making a component based on React Hooks.

These are my dependencies version:

```
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
```

Inside my component "VideoBackground", I created a state with useState where I will store the source of the video and the source of the poster image, like this:

```js
  const [video, setVideo] = useState({
    poster: null,
    src: null,
  });
```

And I am using useEffect hook to work as the componentDidMount function, where I am going to load the video dynamically based on the windows width and add a function to the event listeners in the Browser for reload the video every time that a resizing happens:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    async function handleResize() {
      setVideo(await loadVideo());
    }

    handleResize();

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
      window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
```

The function "loadVideo" that load the video dynamically based on the windows width is a async function because I am using the Dinamic Import syntax provided by React which is a Promise (That is the biggest problem I guess). This is my full component, the "loadVideo" function is at the beginning:

> The "./styles" file is a component based on styled-component lib, I am using it to style my html, it doesn't matter (I guess). But the "Video" component is the video tag from html 5.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { Video, Overlay, Content } from "./styles";

const VideoBackground = ({ children }) => {
  /*
   * Media query of the resource's intended media; this should be used only in a <picture> element
   *
   * Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up)
   * Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up)
   * Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up)
   * Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up)
   * Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down)
   */
  async function loadVideo() {
    const { width } = getWindowDimensions();

    let posterPromise;
    let srcPromise;

    if (width > 1280) {
      posterPromise = import("../../assets/images/code720.jpg");
      srcPromise = import("../../assets/videos/code720.mp4");
    } else if (width > 720) {
      posterPromise = import("../../assets/images/code480.jpg");
      srcPromise = import("../../assets/videos/code480.mp4");
    } else if (width > 480) {
      posterPromise = import("../../assets/images/code320.jpg");
      srcPromise = import("../../assets/videos/code320.mp4");
    } else {
      posterPromise = import("../../assets/images/code240.jpg");
      srcPromise = import("../../assets/videos/code240.mp4");
    }

    const [{ default: poster }, { default: src }] = await Promise.all([
      posterPromise,
      srcPromise,
    ]);

    return {
      poster,
      src,
    };
  }

  /*
   * It returns the width of a window's content area
   */
  function getWindowDimensions() {
    const { innerWidth: width } = window;

    return {
      width,
    };
  }

  const [video, setVideo] = useState({
    poster: null,
    src: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function handleResize() {
      setVideo(await loadVideo());
    }

    handleResize();

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
      window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log("BEFORE RETURN", video);

  return (
    <>
      <Video playsInline autoPlay muted loop poster={video.poster}>
        <source src={video.src} type="video/mp4" />
      </Video>
      <Overlay />
      <Content>{children}</Content>
    </>
  );
};

VideoBackground.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default VideoBackground;
```

**The problem is that the background video is not playing. But the poster image appears**, and I dont know why just the poster image is working.
I put that console.log before the return to try to find out what is happening, and this is what is logged:

```
BEFORE RETURN {poster: null, src: null}
BEFORE RETURN {poster: null, src: null}
BEFORE RETURN {poster: "/static/media/code720.e66bf519.jpg", src: "/static/media/code720.83f62f35.mp4"}
BEFORE RETURN {poster: "/static/media/code720.e66bf519.jpg", src: "/static/media/code720.83f62f35.mp4"}
```

**As you see, the video and the images are loaded normally (But after some time). I think that the problem is that the "useState" assigns a null value to the properties of my state for the first time**, and just after, the "useEffect" calls the "loadVideo" function.

**I tried to import and assign a video to the "useState" for the first time, and normally works!** However, I cannot have a video started with the "useState", because I need to know the screen size before and download the appropriate video.

I also tried to use the "loadVideo" function with the "useState", like this:

```js
const [video, setVideo] = useState(loadVideo());
```

But, it doesnt work because "loadVideo" is async.

**Does anyone have any solution to this problem, or a better way for what I want to do?**

Thank you!

Comment: This error is also appearing on my console:
./src/components/VideoBackground/index.js
  Line 77:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loadVideo'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import()` isn’t loading the video, it just gets the URL. You can do it synchronously.

```
import videoSrc720 from "../../assets/videos/code720.mp4";

if (width>1280) {
    src = videoSrc720;
} ...
```